# click count function not working?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to count every mouse click hits by user so i create a function but it is counting only first clicks. I create a variable to store count values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>clicks</title>

<script type="text/javascript">



function clickcount (){

var clicks=0;   
    document.getElementById('count').value= ++clicks;


    }

document.onclick=clickcount;
</script>


</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="count" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now i got it, if i put the varibale out of the function then it increaments its value. now my question is why we need to put the variable to out of the function

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `clicks` global so that the function continues to increment the same variable...

```
var clicks=0;
function clickcount (){

    document.getElementById('count').value= ++clicks;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you declared `var clicks` inside the function. It gets overwritten with 0 each time it is called. Declare it outside the scope of the function.

```
var clicks = 0;
function clickcount (){
    document.getElementById('count').value= ++clicks;
}
```

The `var` keyword initializes a variable. JavaScript will make available vars defined at a broader scope inside narrower function scope. So calling `var clicks = 0` outside the function places `clicks` at the global (`window` object) scope.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid polluting the global namespace, you could wrap your code in an anonymous function and store your clicks in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

```
(function () { // Begin wrap with anonymous function
    var clicks = 0;
    function clickcount() {
        document.getElementById("count").value = ++clicks;
    }

    // Attach to onload
    window.onload = function () {
        document.onclick = clickcount;
    };
}()); // End wrap with anonymous function
```

Comment: +1 but probably should use the load event to attach the listener and check that `document.getElementById("count")` returns an element before assigning to its *value* property.